# How to utilize miniMax algorithm in Checkers game

Tags: game-design, algorithm, ai

I am sorry...as there are too many articles about it.But I can't simple get this.

I am confused in the implementation of AI. I have generated all possible moves of computer's type pieces. Now I can't decide the flow. Whether I need to start a loop for the possible moves of each piece and assign score to it.... or something else is to be done.

Kindly tell me the proper flow/algorithm for this. Thanks

**UPDATE:**

[MiniMax code](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/31509/minimax-not-working-properlyfor-checkers-game)

Now I coded the algorithm but not getting correct moves. Please help me find out the logical error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One useful thing to understand about minimax for a game like Checkers is that it's traditionally viewed (to first approximation) as *symmetric* - this means that both players can share the same evaluation function, but simply with the signs flipped, or put another way that it's a zero-sum game: if you evaluate the position as being 4/10ths of a checker in your favor, you know that your opponent's evaluation will be -4/10ths of a checker.  This means that you can use the *same* loop structure for both sides and simply multiply by a 'sign flip', rather than having to have different control structures for min and max (or switching within the loop).  In simplest form, the minimax can be done as a classic recursive function, with a termination once you've reached your maximum depth:

```
float EvaluatePositionRecursive(int depth, Board curBoard, float signFactor)
{
  if ( depth >= MAX_DEPTH )
    return EvaluatePositionStatic(curBoard);
  MoveList moves = GenerateMoveList(curBoard);
  float posValue = -FLT_MAX;
  for (move in moves) do {
    Board newBoard = MakeMove(curBoard, move);
    float newValue = signFactor*EvaluatePositionRecursive(depth+1, newBoard, -signFactor);
    if ( newValue > posValue ) posValue = newValue;
  }
  return signFactor*posValue;
}

[...]

  val = EvaluatePositionRecursive(0, thisBoard, 1.0f);
```

This code has the property/requirement that the value returned from the EvaluatePosition functions will always be in terms of one side's evaluation - that is, a positive value of EvaluatePositionRecursive will always be better for (e.g.) black; this is why it (re-)multiplies by signFactor before returning its value.

Note that there's a *lot* that this (pseudo)code doesn't do: it doesn't do any [alpha-beta pruning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-beta_pruning), it doesn't use [transposition tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transposition_table) to cut down on re-evaluating the same position, and it doesn't do any sort of [quiescence search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quiescence_search) or similar adaptive-depth techniques to avoid misevaluating positions where a forced-capture is on the horizon of your search.  What's more, for practical considerations you might not want to use explicit recursion for the minimax, and instead maintain a stack yourself, and there are plenty of other object-management optimizations that you would want to make for a practical implementation of the algorithm (rather than a quick-and-dirty one).  Still, this code should show the core of the algorithm: to evaluate a position, evaluate all of the subpositions from the current side's point of view, pick the 'best', and return that value.

Comment: So, each valid move is abstratcly performed and its score is evaluated. There must ba a track for all the scores. In the end, the move which gives the best score is performed. Am I right?

Comment: Exactly - what I've done here is show you the (abstract) score evaluation function.  I can clean up the 'calling code' to show how the move is chosen, but it's just as you say.

Comment: Thanks alot. Now I am pretty clear about what is to be done. If I get stuck some where, I will seek your advice.