# MiniMax not working properly(for checkers game)

Tags: game-design, algorithm, ai

I am creating a checkers game but My miniMax is not functioning properly,it is always switching between two positions for its move(index 20 and 17).Here is my code:

```
 public double MiniMax(int[] board, int depth, int turn, int red_best, int black_best)
 {   

  int source;
  int dest;
  double MAX_SCORE=-INFINITY,newScore;
  int MAX_DEPTH=3;
  int[] newBoard=new int[32];
  generateMoves(board,turn);
  System.arraycopy(board, 0, newBoard, 0, 32);
  if(depth==MAX_DEPTH)
  { return Evaluation(turn,board);}
  for(int z=0;z<possibleMoves.size();z+=2){
        source=Integer.parseInt(possibleMoves.elementAt(z).toString());
        System.out.println("SOURCE= "+source);

        dest=Integer.parseInt(possibleMoves.elementAt(z+1).toString());//(int[])possibleMoves.elementAt(z+1);
        System.out.println("DEST = "+dest);
        applyMove(newBoard,source,dest);
        newScore=MiniMax(newBoard,depth+1,opponent(turn),red_best, black_best);
        if(newScore>MAX_SCORE)
        {MAX_SCORE=newScore;maxSource=source; maxDest=dest;}//maxSource and maxDest will be used to perform the move.

        if (MAX_SCORE > black_best) 
        {
            if (MAX_SCORE >= red_best) 
                break;  /*  alpha_beta cutoff  */
            else
                black_best = (int) MAX_SCORE;  //the_score
        }
        if (MAX_SCORE < red_best) 
        {
            if (MAX_SCORE<= black_best) 
                break;  /*  alpha_beta cutoff  */
            else
                red_best = (int) MAX_SCORE;  //the_score
        }

  }//for ends


  return MAX_SCORE;
 } //end minimax
```

I am unable to find out the logical mistake. Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your current implementation, this line:

```
return Evaluation(turn, board);
```

should be

```
return Evaluation(rootTurn, board); // rootTurn is black, probably?
```

so your evaluation is in the perspective of the max player. Also,

```
double MAX_SCORE = -INFINITY;
```

should be

```
double MAX_SCORE = turn == rootTurn ? -INFINITY : INFINITY;
```

since if you're minimizing the score as you're doing for red, it can't already be `-INFINITY`.

As you don't seem to be convinced, you can avoid this entire mess of keeping track of sides and whether it's a min or max node, I'd advise using [negamax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negamax). It gives the same result, but is simpler:

```
public double Negamax(int[] board, int depth, int turn, double alpha, double beta) {
    if (depth == 0) 
        return Evaluation(turn, board);
    int[] newBoard = new int[32];
    generateMoves(board, turn);
    System.arraycopy(board, 0, newBoard, 0, 32);
    for (int z = 0; z < possibleMoves.size(); z += 2) {
        int source = Integer.parseInt(possibleMoves.elementAt(z).toString());
        //System.out.println("SOURCE= " + source);
        int dest = Integer.parseInt(possibleMoves.elementAt(z + 1).toString());// (int[])possibleMoves.elementAt(z+1);
        //System.out.println("DEST = " + dest);
        applyMove(newBoard, source, dest);

        double newScore = -Negamax(newBoard, depth - 1, opponent(turn), -beta, -alpha);
        if (newScore >= beta) // alpha-beta cutoff
        return newScore;
            if(newScore > alpha)
                alpha = newScore;
    }// for ends

    return alpha;
} // end minimax
```

In this case it's probably actually faster because you didn't set your alpha bound correctly. It works because of symmetry; `max(a, b) = -min(-a, -b)`. In your root node, you should start the search like this:

```
depth := 3   // what depth to search to?
alpha:= -infinity
foreach move in move list
    do move
    newScore := -Negamax(newBoard, depth - 1, opponent(turn), -infinity, -alpha);
    if newScore > alpha
         alpha := newScore
         bestMove := move
return bestMove
```

Comment: I did the changes as you told, the move didn't happened. If player's color is black, then the move which is to be performed through AI is of red piece, and hence rootTurn is red. Am I right?

Comment: Usually, the max player (black in this case) is the one you start with. I strongly suggest you don't hard code sides into your search; I'll update my answer.

Comment: In the algorithm of your updated answer,                        foreach move in move list
    do move   ,                                                               Here which player's move to be generated?

Comment: The reason we have a root node is that minimax only returns the value of the node, not the best move. We need a different routine to begin the search so that we can choose the best move. From your original implementation it seems you didn't quite realize this. It should be clear that the root represents the program's turn, and having a separate routine also makes it easy to implement other features such as iterative deepening. I'd advise taking a careful look at the code to understand each part. It will make it easier to implement other features.

Comment: Your perception was absolutely right. I first redesigned the whole mechanism and then coded again. Negamax is working correctly but it is very slow. In my root node, I am calling this function for every possible move. Am I doing it correctly? Please provide any technique that can speed up the AI move.And last but not the least, Thanx alot for taking out time to help me.

Comment: Yes, that's right (but make sure you're passing in the `alpha` value in the root as shown in the pseudocode). What do you mean by "slow"? Can it search 4 or 5 plies deep in a few seconds? To speed up the search, you need to improve move ordering and look into reductions. Try implementing iterative deepening, transposition table, killer heuristic, principal variation search, etc. Your original move generation scheme also looks like it can be optimized quite a bit.

Comment: Only the transposition table requires large amounts of memory (but if you can spare a few MB, it will still be worth it).

Comment: I'm sorry, but your problem is too general and this discussion is getting too lengthy. I recommend posting a new question with more specific details.

Answer (score 0):

You say 'it is always switching between two positions for its move(index 20 and 17)' — once you have debugged and tested your search code (and use the negamax suggested by [zong](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/32208/40264)) — you may find that the output still results in an oscillation between two squares.

This may not necessarily be a problem with the search — I've found search result oscillations can occur when the evaluation function doesn't provide sufficient discrimination between the advantages of two different positions in the static eval.

So check both places that your search is scoring as index 20 and index 17 — they may have very similair or identical static scores, and there is insufficient evaluational information for the engine to definitively decide between them.

For debugging negamax, putting in some debug/print statements immediately after the recursive call to negaMax:

```
moveScore = -negaSearch(theBoard, -beta, -alpha, depth-1)

if depth>2 {print (moveIndex, depth, moveScore)}
```